# virtually hosted typo3 site returns a 503 after backend logout

Tags: virtualhost, typo3, apache2.2, http-status-code-503

I am trying to host multiple typo3 managed sites on my remote webserver but whenever I logout from a brand new install I get a 503 error and can't get past that. but I can re-install a typo3 site from the same link. but the default typo3 installed which can be referenced via <**www.mydomain_name.com/typotest**> works fine. below is my default site setup:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /srv/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

############### All other demo sites ################
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /srv/www/site1/
ServerName www.site1.typotest.net

<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride all
</Directory>
<Directory /srv/www/WFS>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>

#ErrorLog ${APACHE_VHOST_LOG_DIR}/site1/error.log
#Loglevel warn
#CustomLog ${APACHE_VHOST_LOG_DIR}/site1/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

######## Site2 ########
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /srv/www/site2/
ServerName www.site2.typotest.net

<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride all
</Directory>
<Directory /srv/www/Monassier>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>

#ErrorLog ${APACHE_VHOST_LOG_DIR}/site2/error.log
#Loglevel warn
#CustomLog ${APACHE_VHOST_LOG_DIR}/site2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

######## site 3 ########
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /srv/www/site3/
ServerName www.site3.typotest.net

<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride all
</Directory>
<Directory /srv/www/HandP>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>

#ErrorLog ${APACHE_VHOST_LOG_DIR}/site3/error.log
#Loglevel warn
#CustomLog ${APACHE_VHOST_LOG_DIR}/site3/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I will also say that I tried copying the .htaccess from the working site to the virtually hosted site but got no results. At this point I am at a loss as to what could be causing this.
Server OS is Debian Lenny and apache 2.2.16.
I would like to add that I have checked the error logs (php ones included) and all I see are access errors

Comment: Does your apache error log give any more details?

Comment: That's the strangest thing... No errors are being generated in the logs except for the access logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight misunderstanding of the framework caused this. It turns out that I had installed a blank package instead of the introduction package. So I was getting the 503 due to there not being any frontend pages created in the blank, and I was trying to access the backend via the front end address.

Comment: It didn't. The only error that kept showing up was a 503 in the access.log.

Comment: I guess because you did not turn on debugging http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2009/03/blank-empty-page-in-typo3.html. That is correct, because visitors should not see error messages (which might disclose security relevant information).

Comment: The only page returned was the "Ooops an error occured page" with the upside down logo. That has no relevant info on it as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, you get two error resulting in a 503 Server Error. The first one is about not having any pages on rootlevel. Once you solved this, the next error is about not having a TypoScript Template at all. Once you solved both issues, you a good to go.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not getting a Apache error log entry, I presume you have got the maintanence mode enabled.

Check your `localconf.php` for the entry:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'][BE][adminOnly] = 1;
```

and change it to

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'][BE][adminOnly] = 0;
```

Comment: No such line in the file (which I assume to be located under the typo3conf directory) http://fpaste.org/FswY/